# how to print logs and measure execution time

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Currently, I'm trying to import a CSV file that contains around 2 million lines. Each line corresponds to a node. I'm using neo4j browser. note: I also tried [neo4j import tool](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/) but it is also somehow working slower.

I tried to run the script with standard cypher query like

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 500 LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///data.csv' AS r 
WITH toInteger(r[0]) AS ID, toInteger(r[1]) AS national_id, toInteger(r[2]) as passport_no, toInteger(r[3]) as status, toInteger(r[4]) as activation_date 
MERGE (p:Customer {ID: ID}) SET p.national_id = national_id, p.passport_no = passport_no, p.status = status, p.activation_date = activation_date
```

This works very slow.

Later I tried.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('CALL apoc.load.csv(\'file:/data.csv\') yield list as r return r','WITH toInteger(r[0]) AS ID, toInteger(r[1]) AS national_id, toInteger(r[2]) as passport_no, toInteger(r[3]) as status, toInteger(r[4]) as activation_date MERGE (p:Customer {ID: ID}) SET p.national_id = national_id, p.passport_no = passport_no, p.status = status, p.activation_date = activation_date',
{batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true});
```

This one seems like working faster since the `parallel` option is `true`. **BUT** I want to measure the execution time of one batch.

How could I print something on the neo4j browser?

How could I measure execution time for **one batch**?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your first query uses a batch size of 500, and your second one uses a batch size that is 20 times larger. You need to use the same batch size to do a valid comparison.
2. Since your query requires a large number of batches (at least 200), dividing the total time by the number of batches should be a reasonable approximation of the average time per batch.
3. Have you created an [index](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/administration/indexes-for-search-performance/) on `:Customer(ID)`? That should help to speed up your queries.
4. You should consider whether you should use the [ON CREATE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-create) expression with your `MERGE` clause. Right now, the `SET` clause is always executed, even if the node already exists.

Comment: How could index help me? I think they only help during search queries. Shouldn't indexes need to be created after data is generated?

Comment: Also, the index link you sent say about indexes "... cost of additional storage space and slower writes, ..."

Comment: I just found another thing here https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/load-csv/ it seems to contradict with my previous comment "When using MERGE or MATCH with LOAD CSV we need to make sure we have an index or a unique constraint on the property that we are merging on. This will ensure that the query executes in a performant way."

Comment: The `MERGE` operation can take advantage of an index to determine if a node already exists. Without an index, your merges would take incrementally longer to execute over time because neo4j would have to scan all the existing `Customer` nodes (up to 2 million!) to detect a duplicate. And I see from your answer that you have verified this.

Comment: thank you. Your answer and comments are informative to me.

Answer (score 0):

The key thing is adding "unique constraint" before adding any data. This makes the process a lot faster. I see that from https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/current/cypher-intro/load-csv/
[image: suggests constraints]
 Now a script like this

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Movie) ASSERT n.no IS UNIQUE;
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 10000
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///data/MovieData.csv' AS r
WITH r[0] AS no, toInteger(r[1]) AS status, toInteger(r[2]) as activation_date
MERGE (p:Movie {no: no})
ON CREATE SET p.status = status, p.activation_date = activation_date
```

adding 1 million nodes in 1 minute. Before it was more than 2-3 days.

Comment: A unique constraint automatically creates an index for you, and the *index* is what causes the performance boost. If you just created an index, you'd get the same boost. But, of course, you should create a unique constraint instead if you really want to enforce uniqueness as well.